# Get a XML list and return values with number of times listed

Tags: php, xml

I am connecting to an XML file and trying to create a list that shows each value listed one time, followed by the number of times it is listed. So if the value shows in there 10 times, I want 1 entry with the # 10 by it.

I have everything working, but I can not seem to get it to update the number instead of adding a new entry to the list. Something is not correct, but I am not able to step through like I would in JS to test it. (This is in PHP by the way)

XML FILE (Simplified)- There are a lot more entries with many more 's per `<result>` but this should give an idea of the layout of the XML FILE

```
<results>
   <result date="2016-05-17">
      <row>
         <label>www.url1.com</label>
      </row>
      <row>
         <label>www.url2.com</label>
      </row>
   </result>
   <result date="2016-05-19">
      <row>
         <label>www.url1.com</label>
      </row>
   </result>
</results>
```

PHP

```
$refferers = simplexml_load_file('https://url.com');

$refferer_urls = array( );
$refferer_html = '';

foreach ($refferers->result as $result) {   
    if ($result->row[0]) {  
        foreach($result->row as $refferal) {
            $the_url = $refferal->label;
            if( go_refferer_exsists( $refferer_urls, $the_url ) ) {
                for($i = 0; $i < count($refferer_urls); $i++) {
                    if( $refferer_urls[$i]["url"] == $the_url ) {
                        $refferer_urls[$i]["quantity"]++;
                    }
                }

            } else {
                array_push($refferer_urls, array(
                    "url"       => $the_url,
                    "quantity"  => 1,
                ));
            }
        }   
    }   
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($refferer_urls); $i++) {

    $refferer_html .= '<table>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td scope="row" width="75%">
           <label for="tablecell"><strong>' . $refferer_urls[$i]["url"] . '</strong></label></td>
         <td>' . $refferer_urls[$i]["quantity"] . '</td>
    </tr>
    </table>';
}

function go_refferer_exsists($the_array, $value) {

    for($i = 0; $i < count($the_array); $i++) {
        if ( $the_array[$i]["url"] == $value ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

RETURNS

```
www.url1.com    1
www.url2.com    1
www.url1.com    1
```

Comment: you just want to count the number of `url`'s?, just use the good ol'  `$myarray[$the_url]['count']++` reassignment key pair in a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you'll find that you're having difficulty diagnosing the problem in your code because it's overly complex for what it's doing. You can simplify your logic a lot by indexing your `$refferer_urls` [sic] array by the URL itself, and just store the number of quantity as the value, e.g.:

```
foreach ($refferers->result as $result) {   
    if (!$result->row[0]) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($result->row as $refferal) {
        $the_url = (string) $refferal->label;
        // Initialize the key
        if (!array_key_exists($the_url, $refferer_urls)) {
            $refferer_urls[$the_url] = 0;
        }
        // Increment the count for it
        $refferer_urls[$the_url]++;
    }   
}

foreach ($refferer_urls as $url => $quantity) {
    $refferer_html .= '<table>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td scope="row" width="75%">
           <label for="tablecell"><strong>' . $url . '</strong></label></td>
         <td>' . $quantity . '</td>
    </tr>
    </table>';
}
```

Please note, I've also tweaked the spacing in your code and used `continue` as opposed to another level of indentation at the start of your first `foreach`. I've also swapped the `while` for a `foreach` in the second loop since you're looping an array straight through so it's cleaner to do it this way.

[Example.](https://eval.in/578014)

Answer (score 0):

Consider an even less complex solution with [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed specifically to transform XML files, even to HTML. Below uses the Muenchian Method (the popular, efficient grouping method in XSLT 1.0 using indexing) to count the `<label>` values. PHP like most general purpose languages maintains an XSLT 1.0 processor. In this solution, no looping is used:

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl file to be used below)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="labelkey" match="result/row" use="label" />

  <xsl:template match="results">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="result/row[generate-id() = 
                                   generate-id(key('labelkey',label)[1])]"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="result/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('labelkey',label)[1])]">
    <tr valign="top">      
      <td scope="row" width="75%">
         <label for="tablecell">
            <strong>
               <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
            </strong>
         </label>
      </td>
      <td scope="row" width="75%">
         <xsl:value-of select="count(. | key('labelkey', label))"/>
      </td>      
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL SOURCES
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xslfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xslfile->load('Transform.xsl');

// TRANFORM SOURCE WITH XSL
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslfile); 
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// ECHO STRING OUTPUT    
echo $newXml;

// <table>
//   <tr valign="top">
//     <td scope="row" width="75%">
//       <label for="tablecell">
//         <strong>www.url1.com</strong>
//       </label>
//     </td>
//     <td scope="row" width="75%">2</td>
//   </tr>
//   <tr valign="top">
//     <td scope="row" width="75%">
//       <label for="tablecell">
//         <strong>www.url2.com</strong>
//       </label>
//     </td>
//     <td scope="row" width="75%">1</td>
//   </tr>
// </table>
```